# Discord.py embed thumbnail direct from website url

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, discord.py, embed

I'm not able to embed a thumbnail using a link from the image source on the website. Have managed to for multiple sites, just seems to be this one.  We are outputting this to a database which does work, so the image url is in the database it's just when embedding as a thumbnail in discord.

```
  )
        embed.set_thumbnail(
            url=Image
        )

.....

driver.get('https://www.sevenstore.com/launches/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)

elements = driver.find_elements(
    By.XPATH, value='//div[@class="nodecor "]/span[1]/span[1]')

for element in elements:
    actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
    actionChains.move_to_element(element).perform()

expected_condition = EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '//div[@class="nodecor "]/span[1]/span[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[3]/a[1]'))

wait.until(expected_condition)


product_image = driver.find_elements(
    By.XPATH, value='//div[@class="nodecor "]/span[1]/span[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/a[1]/img[1]')

 Image = product_image[i].get_attribute('src')
```

Nothing wrong with the image, works fine if I download it locally or upload it to a file upload site and use that link. Missing something with the website or a wait command? just not sure. See above code.

Website - https://www.sevenstore.com/launches/

We're trying to grab any image doesn't matter, but example HTML attached.

any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you printed the HTML you get as a response to see if you're actually getting what you think you're getting?

Comment: Yes, as stated we're outputting the image url to a spreadsheet and the link is fine. We're able to access this link and view the image no issues. It's something to do with the embed side relating to the website, because as said if we upload this image to a random upload site and use that link it loads the embed.

There's absolutely no issues with the data we are scraping, we are getting all info we require. It's simply just embedding the thumbnail